# How to use TextBox input to change a value by firing a RemoteEvent

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to figure this out for about 30 minutes and have had no luck. I'm stumped and cannot figure this out.

I am trying to make a script that allows the player to change their money by inputting a number into their TextBox.

Local Script (child of TextBox)

```lua
script.Parent.FocusLost:Connect(function(enter)
    if enter then
        -- this is to check the player's input
        local finalvalue = tonumber(script.Parent.Text)
        print(script.Parent.Text)
        -- if it was not a number
        if finalvalue == nil then
            script.Parent.Text = "Not a number"
            wait(1)
            -- just making sure that it doesn't delete the player's new input
            if script.Parent.Text == "Not a number" then
                script.Parent.Text = ""
            end
        else
            -- firing the money remote event with the finalvalue variable
            game.ReplicatedStorage.ChangeMoney:FireServer(finalvalue)
            print("fired")
            -- resetting the textbox
            script.Parent.Text = ""
        end

    end
end)
```

Server Script (child of ServerScriptService)

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.ChangeMoney.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(amt)

    game.ReplicatedStorage.Money.Value = tonumber(amt)
    print("money changed to " .. tostring(amt))
end)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `OnServerEvent` receives a `Player` in addition to a tuple of arguments passed by `FireServer()`.

It looks like there is just one money value for the entire server, so assuming that the value you're trying to change is independent of the player who sent the `RemoteEvent`, you can just change your function declaration to accept the `Player` and just disregard it after that:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ChangeMoney.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, amt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That would explain why the print statement in the Server Script was printing my username. I'll accept the answer when the timer on it ends.